# How to retrieve feed from Facebook when Facebook stopped supporting rss feed?

Tags: facebook, rss, rss-reader, facebook-feed

Facebook has recently stopped supporting rss feed. Are there any ways to retrieve rss feed from  Graph API or some more easy way to retrieve feed from Facebook without much hassel?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

Comment: Yup, as of today all the rss feeds (and json option) in the format: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=$pageid&format=rss20  stopped working.  Looks like token options may be required from here on out.

Comment: Officially deprecated - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a free service that work in this moment :
http://fbrss.com/

Answer (score 0):

This PHP script converts the Graph API JSON feed to RSS:
https://github.com/khawkins98/facebook-json-to-rss

Comment: Link only answers aren't suitable for SO - primarily because if the link's content changes (or disappears), but also because it doesn't explain how this link solves the OP's question.

Comment: I'm not a coder. Can you be more specific on how to use this script?